# How to make a button work under certain conditions?

Tags: javascript

I am making a html/javascript game were its a basic fighting game using a button ( kinda like pokemon wear you push a button and he does a set attack) and my friend pointed out if you spam the attack button you will attack multiple times. Is there something in javascript were you can prevent the button from working once it is pushed?

The only method I could think of was to make a css class and have two buttons ( one that works, and a mimic that doesn't) and use the document.getElementsByid('button's id).class and have it change once the button is pushed and have it changed back once the comupter has attacked. Is there a easyer way to do this?

Comment: Just change the button state to disabled on press.

Comment: set a disabled option at button. when attack is finished remove the attribute

Answer (score 2):

Set the [disabled property](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_disabled.asp) to `true` when the button is clicked, and then set it back to `false` after the computer attacks:

```
document.getElementById("buttonId").disabled = true;

document.getElementById("buttonId").disabled = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

After clicking set the disabled property on the button:

```
<button disabled>Attack!</button>
```

You can do it your javascript with:

```
document.getElementById(id).disabled = "disabled";
```